# Recursively append folder name to the files in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I would like to append my folder name to all the available .txt files inside a subfolder. Below is the file/directory structure. I need to achieve this in Windows BATCH script.

> C:\Source\Source1\1\a.txt C:\Source\Source1\1\b.txt
>
> C:\Source\Source1\2\a.txt C:\Source\Source1\2\b.txt
>
> C:\Source\Source2\3\a.txt C:\Source\Source2\3\b.txt

The above files should be renamed like below:

> C:\Source\Source1\1\1_a.txt C:\Source\Source1\1\1_b.txt
>
> C:\Source\Source1\2\2_a.txt C:\Source\Source1\2\2_b.txt
>
> C:\Source\Source2\3\3_a.txt C:\Source\Source2\3\3_b.txt

Similary, I have Source1...Source30 and under each source directory, I will have multiple folders with different numbers. I need to rename all the files under these directories and append the number(directory name) to the file name.

So far below is what I wrote:

```
for %%* in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nx*
echo %CurrDirName%

for /r %%x in (*.txt) do ren "%%x" "%CurrDirName%_%%x"
```

With this, I am able to achieve it in a single directory. I couldn't make it recursive. Could you guys please help me with this.

Comment: This is not dos, please remove the *dos* tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S "C:\Source\*.txt"') do (
    for %%g in ("%%~dpG.") do ECHO rename "%%~fG" "%%~nxg_%%~nxG"
)
pause
```

where the `FOR` loops are:

- outer `%%G` loop creates a *static list* of `.txt` files (recursively), and
- inner `%%g` loop gets the parent folder of every particular file.

The `rename` command is merely displayed using `ECHO` for debugging purposes. To make it operational, remove word `ECHO` (no sooner than debugged).

Moreover, I'd consider checking whether a particular file is already renamed…

Comment: Is there an easy way to append the folder name instead or prepending it? But in a way that the file extension is kept, of course.