# Recursively append folder name to files in it and moves all files to base folder Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, cmd, scripting

I would like to append recursively folder (and parent folder) names to each *.txt files that folder contains. After that I want to move all files to base folder and delete all folders. I need to achieve this in Windows BATCH script. For examle:

```
\BaseFolder\A01\B01\EX1.TXT
\BaseFolder\C01\EX2.TXT
\BaseFolder\EX3.TXT
```

To:

```
\BaseFolder\A01-B01-EX1.TXT
\BaseFolder\C01-EX2.TXT
\BaseFolder\EX3.TXT
```

To do this i've found this solution thanks to JosefZ:

[Recursively append folder name to the files in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565519/recursively-append-folder-name-to-the-files-in-windows-batch-file/59051550#59051550)

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S "C:\Source\*.txt"') do (
    for %%g in ("%%~dpG.") do rename "%%~fG" "%%~nxg_%%~nxG"
)
pause
```

where the FOR loops are:

- outer %%G loop creates a static list of .txt files (recursively), and
- inner %%g loop gets the parent folder of every particular file.

But this solve only a part of my goal. Can anyone help?

Comment: The solution you linked can only handle one sub-directory level and it does not move any files but just rename them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should accomplish what you want, namely moving and renaming the files as predefined and deleting the remaining empty sub-directories (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=.\BaseFolder" & rem // (target base directory)
set "_MASK=*.txt"        & rem // (file search pattern)
set "_CHAR=-"            & rem // (separator character)

rem // Switch to target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop through list of relative paths of matching files:
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ('
        xcopy /L /S /I "%_MASK%" "%TEMP%" ^| find ":"
    ') do (
        rem // Store current relative file path, initialise variables:
        set "FILE=%%F" & set "NAME=" & set /A "NUM=0"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!` and `^`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Loop through all individual elements of file relative path:
        for %%I in ("!FILE:\=" "!") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Store current path element and count them:
            set "ITEM=%%~I" & set /A "NUM+=1"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Build new file name and pass it over `endlocal` barrier:
            for /F "delims=" %%N in ("!NAME!%_CHAR%!ITEM!") do (
                endlocal
                set "NAME=%%N"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        rem // Finalise new file name:
        if defined _CHAR set "NAME=!NAME:*%_CHAR%=!"
        rem // Actually move and rename the current file:
        > nul move "!FILE!" "!NAME!"
        rem // Switch to parent directory of current file:
        pushd "!FILE!\.." && (
            rem // Loop through parent directory elements:
            for /L %%N in (2,1,!NUM!) do (
                rem // Try to remove parent directory when empty, go one up:
                set "DD=!CD!" & cd ".." & 2> nul rd "!DD!"
            )
            rem // Return to previous working directory:
            popd
        )
        endlocal
     )
     rem // return to original working directory:
     popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 'fun' idea:

```bat
@Set "BaseFolder=C:\Users\Mustafa\BaseFolder"
@ForFiles /P "%BaseFolder%" /S /M *.txt /C "Cmd /C If @IsDir==FALSE For /F 0x22Tokens=*Delims=.\0x22 %%# In (@RelPath)Do @If Not 0x22%%#0x22==@File Set 0x22_=%%#0x22&Call Move /Y 0x22%BaseFolder%\%%#0x22 0x22%BaseFolder%\%%_:\=-%%0x22>NUL"
```

Please note that this untested solution is very likely to have command line length limitations. I would therefore avoid it if your initial base folder is deep within the volume and/or its tree is deep or carries long file and directory names. Given that cautionary information, please remember to adjust the full path value on line one as necessary.

Comment: Nice one! Since you already use `call` to delay expansion you could also change `%BaseFolder%` to `%%BaseFolder%%` in the `move` command line in order to delay expansion also there and so to reduce the overall command line length seen by `forfiles`, which stupidly limits it to only 253 characters. Anyway, note that your approach does not clean up empty directories like desired...

Comment: Noted @aschipfl, I left the emptying off because it would have likely suffered character length issues, _(thanks for confirming that and it's number)_. It should also be a simple, remove 'empty' directories routine on a subsequent line, without much effort. I could have made that effort, but as the OP hadn't made any attempt at the task, I figured that a simple search should give them that anyhow.